# Four-Prong Relay Useage

Tags: relay

I apologize for the basic question - I'm just getting into electronics and have come across a diagram that I don't understand (or more accurately, don't want to risk frying my Arduino with not understanding).

I recently bought a relay from Radioshack. I've copied the diagram:

[image]

I assume that I apply the large current through 2 and it goes out 4, and then either 1 or 3 is to switch it off and on? Can someone confirm or correct me on that?

Thanks!

Comment: That's the right way to use the pins on the relay, but we'll need to know more about the relay (coil voltage and current) before we can help ensure that your Arduino will play nicely with it.  Also note that you'll always want a reverse-biased diode in parallel with the coil terminals (1 and 3) to absorb inductive transients created when the coil is turned off.

Comment: Ok:
Voltage: 5VDC (same as Arduino)
Coil resistance: 250 Ohms
Contact rating: 0.5A 125VDC
Nominal current: 20mA
Also, which terminal would turn it on, and which off?

Comment: Check out this wikipedia article on the Flyback diode, this is a must: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is with a circuit like the following.  I've added the pins of your relay in red.  Set the output HIGH to turn on the relay and LOW to turn it off.

[image]

Your Arduino pins can sink up to 40mA, so it is possible to drive the relay directly if you want to, though any mishaps may blow up your Arduino instead of taking out the external transistor.

[image]

Note that with this second approach you will need to set your output to LOW in order to turn the relay on, and HIGH to turn the relay off (which can be counter-intuitive).